# .txt file to .xlsx file (600 rows and 40 columns)

Tags: c#, excel, text-files

I have a program that combines three text files and put them all into one and sorts them all out alphabetically. I was wondering how I could possibly put this onto an excel spreadsheet without downloading and using the excellibrary (if that's possible).

Heres my code that combines all three files if that helps.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // merge files button
    {

        System.IO.StreamWriter output = new System.IO.StreamWriter("OUTPUT.txt");

        String[] parts = new String[1000];
        String[] parts2 = new String[1000];

        parts = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);       //gets filepath from top textbox
        parts2 = File.ReadAllLines(textBox2.Text);      //gets filepath from middle textbox

        String[] head = File.ReadAllLines(headingFileBox.Text); //header file array


        //merging the two files onto one list, there is no need to merge the header file because no math is being
        //computed on it
        var list = new List<String>();
        list.AddRange(parts);
        list.AddRange(parts2);


        //foreach loop to write the header file into the output file
        foreach (string h in head)
        {
            output.WriteLine(h);
        }
        //prints 3 blank lines for spaces
        output.WriteLine();
        output.WriteLine();
        output.WriteLine();


        String[] partsComb = list.ToArray(); // string array that takes in the list
        Array.Sort(partsComb);
        //foreach loop to combine files and sort them by 1st letter
        foreach (string s in partsComb)
        {
            partsComb.Equals(s);
            output.WriteLine(s);
        }
        output.Close();
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a CSV, which excel reads just fine?

Comment: Unfortunately, creating an .xlsx sheet without the use of any 3rd-party library will be a lot of work. Make a .csv (as suggested in the answers below) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at creating it in a CSV format (Comma-separated values). Excel naturally opens it up and loads the data into the rows and cells.

Basic CSV looks like this:

```
"Bob","Smith","12/1/2012"
"Jane","Doe","5/10/2004"
```

Some things are optional like wrapping everything in quotes, but needed if your data may contain the delimiter.

Comment: @Stock Just output like you would for any other TXT file, but instead change the extension to be CSV. You just need to separate your columns by a comma and optionally wrap the column data in quotes.

Comment: Well the file has 40 different columns and 600 rows, would I have to hardcode it all to use the CSV format?

Comment: @Stock If your data isn't already split out by rows and columns, then you need to do that which you would have had to do with Excel anyway. Make an array for each row to hold your columns and then add that array to an array of rows. Once you have that, you need to build a couple of for loops to output the text.

Comment: Interesting, I'm pretty new to programming and C# but doesn't my code up at the top put the rows into an array? I've made an array for each of the columns but don't really know how to implement it into the code.

Comment: @Stock You have rows, but I didn't see columns. Good luck. There should be lots of tutorials out there for creating simple CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a [comma separated values (CSV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, that's easy enough to generate with string manipulation and will load in Excel. If you need an excel specific format and are okay with XLSX, you can populate one with some XML manipulation and a ZIP library.

Fair warning, you will have to be careful about escaping commas and new lines if you choose a traditional CSV file. There are libraries that handle that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Excel package plus: http://EPPlus.codeplex.com
It's free, lightweight, and can create xlsx files.

Comment: It's designed for C#; I've used it a bit in VS 2012